# using SQL to Create a Login page in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in .Net.  I created a login page with an SQL connection in Visual Studio 2008.
But I want to use the code in Visual Studio 2010.

Please help me.

Comment: You can just open it in visual studio 2010 and it will convert the project for you

Comment: I think thats an answer not a comment. :)

Comment: it doesn't matters if you code in VS 2008 and open in 2010. But it asks for to change your target framework to 4.0 if you open VS 2008's code in VS 2010. just click on Ok/Yes and go ahead..there is nothing to do with your code done in 2008 or vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can just open it in visual studio 2010 and it will convert the project for you